# Codeigniter - htmlspecialchars() on input not working

Tags: codeigniter, input, xss, htmlspecialchars

I'm using `htmlspecialchars()` on `input` field for `user last name` to prevent `xss`, but it's not working..
Let's say `$user_data->user_last_name;` is my `user last name`, so I did:

```
htmlspecialchars( $user_data->user_last_name, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
```

When I try to save user last name as `'Lastname<script>alert("xss")</script>'`, I get `JS alert` with `'xss'` message.

Any clue maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, may work:

```
$string = htmlentities($user_data->user_last_name, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-15');
```

While retrieving the input you should use:

```
$value = $this->input->post('input_name', true);
```

Here, `true` will clean the input value of `xss`.

Comment: thanks for effort, realized later on that I was watching in wrong view -.-".

Answer (score 0):

> It works, but The output is interpreted by your browser as HTML

**// use That Simple Line Above Your Code To See The Real output**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain');
?>
```